# excel progress percentage done

Tags: excel, percentage

Stuped my brain here..

```
    A   B
1   Task1   0%
2   Task2   0%
3   Task3   26%
4   Task4   0%
5   Task5   0%
6   Task6   6%
```

I need the "progress" on these percentages. Explain: B1 is 0% done. B3 is 26% done.
I would like (in row B7) a "Total Progress".

All tasks done is 100% done. But each task is a sub percentage of this.
Example gives 32% total. But that is not 32% total progress.

Comment: Umm... `SUM(B) / (COUNT(A) * 100)` ?

Comment: @PaddyCollins on a column with 0% in all rows, it gives an average of 5% ;-)

Comment: @dubes calc gives 538%

Comment: @dubes think you are on to something though..

Comment: Check your numbers are actually numbers and not text or something else. I just replicated your worksheet and I got an average of 5.33%. When I make them all 0 I get an average of 0.

Comment: Since your data is already in % you don't need to do * 100 and that eventually means @PaddyCollins is right and all you need is to average it. `=AVERAGE(B1:B6)` is 5.33%. Or possibly we are misunderstanding your need. What do you expect to see as the outcome for the data sample you have provided?

Comment: Sorry.. Workbook/Formula/Calculate/Manual ;-(
Fixed and @PaddyCollins works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the average of the percentages:

```
=AVERAGE(B1:B7)
```